# This perl script renames all files in a directory to have an equal amount of digits

Tags: perl

I took a lot of pictures with my camera and I wanted to make a time-lapse out of them. The camera saved the pictures as `picture1`, `picture2` ... `picture956` etc. but the time-lapse software I'm using only accepts numbers of equal length like this: `picture001`, `picture002`, `picture003` etc.

I thought Perl would be a good fit for this kind of problem so I gave it a shot. This is a shorter and translated version of the original code so if anything is unclear I can change it to the longer version.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

print "Give the path to the directory where the pictures are stored:\n";
my $filename = <STDIN>;

chomp $filename;
chdir $filename or die "Couldn't change the directory: $!\n";
my @files  = <*>;
#gives a list of all filehandles in the given directory

my $amount_of_digits = int( log($#files)/log(10) +1);
#how many digits should the new number have?
#Example: If there are 400 files -> 3 digits per file: 001, 002 etc

foreach my $file (@files){
    next if($file =~ /^\.$/);
    next if($file =~ /^\.\.$/);
    #skip the . and .. files
    print "$file\n";
    if ($file =~ /(\d+)/){
        my $amount_of_padded_zeroes = $amount_of_digits - length($1);
        if($amount_of_padded_zeroes > 0){
            my $new_number =  '0' x $amount_of_padded_zeroes . $1;     
            (my $new_name = $file) =~ s/$1/$new_number/;
            print "Changing name too: $new_name\n"; 
            rename ($file, $new_name) or die "Couldn't rename the file: $!";
        }
    }
}

print "Program completed. Press any key to continue.\n";
my $einde = <STDIN>;
```

The code works but I wanted to know if there is a better/cleaner/shorter/more Pearlesque way to do this. I'm learning Perl for uni so any feedback is welcome. I suspect this problem is so trivial in Perl that there might be readable one-liners that are able to replace all of this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you suspect, this can be done in fewer lines, but it's not a one-liner.

> ```
> use strict;
> use warnings;
> use diagnostics;
> ```

Always a good idea.  Consider `use warnings FATAL => "all"` so that you don't miss any.

---

> ```
> my $filename = <STDIN>;
> ```

A command-line argument or environment variable is the typical way to do this, in Perl and most other languages.  Directory variables oughtn't be named `$filename`.

```
  my $dir = ( shift or $ENV{TIMELAPSE_DIRECTORY} or die "usage: $0 directory\n" );
```

---

> ```
> chdir $filename or die "Couldn't change the directory: $!\n";
> …
> rename ($file, $new_name) or die "Couldn't rename the file: $!";
> ```

The fat-arrow `=>` can replace a comma and improve readability in some cases.  Dropping parens is another good readability boost, when done judiciously.  Unless the line number where `die` occurred is interesting, suppress it by appending a newline to the message.  And finally, it's a good habit to include in error messages the data that produced them, as in:

```
 rename $file => $new_name or die "Couldn't rename '$file' to '$new_name': $!\n";
```

---

> ```
> my @files  = <*>;
> #gives a list of all filehandles in the given directory
> ```

Filenames, not filehandles.  It would be reasonable to filter this list to contain actual files, excluding directories:

```
my @files  = grep -f, <*>;
```

And maybe even by name:

```
my @files = grep { -f and /\.( png | jpe?g | tga )$/xi } <*>;
```

---

> ```
> my $amount_of_digits = int( log($#files)/log(10) +1);
> ```

`$#files` is the largest index in that zero-based array.  With 10 files, the last is `$files[9]` and the math returns `1` instead of the `2` we need.  The size of the array is one bigger and retrieved as `@files` in scalar context (`log()` imposes scalar context for us, which is convenient).

`width` is a good name for this variable.

Avoid an uncaught exception by checking that `@files` is non-empty.

And the parens around `int` can be omitted.

```
die "nothing to do!\n" unless @files;
my $width = int log(@files)/log(10) + 1;
```

But this is still no good!  `log(1000)/log(10)` is `3` in Perl and in real life.  But `int( log(1000)/log(10) )` is `2`!   This happens because [floating-point math is imperfect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).  Luckily Perl will let us cheat by taking the length of a number that's been silently converted  to a string:

```
my $width = length scalar @files;
```

---

> ```
> foreach my $file (@files){
> ```

`for` is the idiomatic alternative to `foreach`.

---

> ```
>     if ($file =~ /(\d+)/){
>         my $amount_of_padded_zeroes = $amount_of_digits - length($1);
>         if($amount_of_padded_zeroes > 0){
>             my $new_number =  '0' x $amount_of_padded_zeroes . $1;     
>             (my $new_name = $file) =~ s/$1/$new_number/;
>             print "Changing name too: $new_name\n";
> ```

`sprintf` is the function to use for leading zeroes.  It can go right in the `s///` replacement by using the `/e`xecute modifier.  If the replace fails, skip to `next` file.

```
             (my $new_name = $file) =~ s/(\d+)/ sprintf "%0${width}d" => $1 /e or next;
```

---

> ```
> rename ($file, $new_name) or die "Couldn't rename the file: $!";
> ```

It's good practice to ensure you have something to do, and that you aren't overwriting an existing file here:

```
next if $new_name eq $file;
die "$new_name (from $file) already exists!\n" if -f $new_name;
```

---

> ```
> print "Program completed. Press any key to continue.\n";
> my $einde = <STDIN>;
> ```

I think you know how I feel about this.  Should you decide to keep it, only the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key will actually proceed.

Putting it all together:

```
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use diagnostics;

my $dir = ( shift or $ENV{TIMELAPSE_DIRECTORY} or die "usage: $0 directory\n" );
chdir $dir or die "Couldn't change directory to $dir: $!\n";
my @files = grep { -f and /\.( png | jpe?g | tga )$/xi } <*>;
die "nothing to do!\n" unless @files;
my $width = length scalar @files;

for my  $file (@files) { 
    (my $new_name = $file) =~ s/(\d+)/ sprintf "%0${width}d" => $1 /e or next;
    next if $new_name eq $file;
    die "$new_name (from $file) already exists!\n" if -f $new_name;
    rename $file => $new_name or die "Couldn't rename '$file' to '$new_name': $!\n";
}
print "Program completed.\n"
```

**Reader exercise:** improve this program to number the files from 1 to n, even if the original numbers don't start at 1 or have gaps!

Comment: Remove diagnostics in production. They take about a second to load and add no value once your program works. They just explain things after there were errors or warnings.

Comment: Your diagnostics advice is perfectly reasonable; the time estimate seems high.  For me, it took 95ms to load diagnostics (2012-vintage Core i3, in 1.6GHz powersave mode, with no reason for diagnostics.pm to be in disk cache).  On a more recent Core i5 it takes about half that time, 50ms.

Comment: you are right. I misremembered the time it takes. My advice was based on [my experience here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13566980/1331451), but that is a few years ago, when hardware was less powerful. But indeed it was only 300ms. No idea where I had the second from.

Comment: It's really hard to see where your code jumps. `die` and `next` shouldn't be hidden halfway into a statement. Add a line break before `or die`, `or next`, etc.

Comment: those are exceptions.  Noticing them is not required to understand the program flow, and they're not important enough to merit the beginning of a line.